# Get Input from the source code itself C++

Tags: c++, input, user-input

I want to do something like this

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

/*

//IF 
//ASKED FOR INPUT :
//12

*/ 

int main()
{
  int myInt;
  std::cin >> myInt;
  std::cout << myInt;
}
```

I want this snippet to print `12`

I want the code to do something like what the commented part states.

I know I can use standard output and just type it in there. But, my IDE dosen't allow that and I don't want to read it from a file either. Any suggestions?

Before, I thought I can use `#define`to redefine the purpose of `cin` and read from the top of the file instead. But, I'm not sure if it would work or how to implement it either.

Comment: *"my IDE dosen't allow that"*. Strange, which IDE do you use?

Comment: @Jarod42 It's a custom IDE made by the school. That's why :(

Comment: One option is to receive the value as a program parameter. You would need to use `int main(int argc, char **argv) {}` and configure your IDE to pass a parameter when it runs the code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `stringstream` might help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    std::stringstream ss("42");

    int i;
    ss >> i;
    std::cout << i;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/KiA1Xu)

Comment: You could use a raw string literal so that the OP can just copy and paste the contents of a file into the source code with the line breaks and everything.

Comment: @FeiXiang Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: @DevanshSharma: raw string literal is `R"(some_text which may contain quote as " or backslash as \ )"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two different builds based on a `#define` value.  Use stringstream as an input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#define USING_FAKE_STREAM
#ifdef USING_FAKE_STREAM
    std::stringstream g_ss;
    void initStream()
    {
        g_ss << "12\n";
    }

    std::istream& getInputStream()
    {
        return g_ss;
    }
    #else
    void initStream()
    {
    }

    std::istream& getInputStream()
    {
        return std::cin;
    }
#endif

int main()
{
    initStream();

    auto& inputStream = getInputStream();

    inputStream >> myInt;
    std::cout << myInt;

    return 0;
}
```